Semaphore Leakage During MultiProcessing in the context of NLP
I set up some stack traceback and multiprocessing log statements

zsh: bus error  python3.10 -W 'default' circuit_gpt2.py
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:224:
> UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore
> objects to clean up at shutdown   warnings.warn('resource_tracker:
> There appear to be %d '

I use clean up at the end of program using the following code
# Cleanup mechanism at the end of the program
for process in multiprocessing.active_children():
    process.terminate()
    process.join()

and use cpu on my m1 (8 core, 16GM RAM)device.
Also can't seem to find where it creates semlock with handle 8.
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 8

Here's the full stack trace.
    File "/Users/crayhippo/feature-circuits/circuit_gpt2.py", line 342, in <module>
    model = LanguageModel(args.model, device_map=device, dispatch=True)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nnsight/models/LanguageModel.py", line 145, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nnsight/models/NNsightModel.py", line 72, in __init__
    self._model = self._load(self._model_key, *args, **kwargs).to("meta")
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nnsight/models/LanguageModel.py", line 149, in _load
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(repo_id, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/configuration_auto.py", line 928, in from_pretrained
    config_dict, unused_kwargs = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 631, in get_config_dict
    config_dict, kwargs = cls._get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 686, in _get_config_dict
    resolved_config_file = cached_file(
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 398, in cached_file
    resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 114, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1132, in hf_hub_download
    warnings.warn(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/warnings.py", line 109, in _showwarnmsg
    sw(msg.message, msg.category, msg.filename, msg.lineno,
  File "/Users/crayhippo/feature-circuits/circuit_gpt2.py", line 35, in warn_with_traceback
    traceback.print_stack()
  File "/Users/crayhippo/feature-circuits/circuit_gpt2.py", line 342, in <module>
    model = LanguageModel(args.model, device_map=device, dispatch=True)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nnsight/models/LanguageModel.py", line 145, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_key, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nnsight/models/NNsightModel.py", line 72, in __init__
    self._model = self._load(self._model_key, *args, **kwargs).to("meta")
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nnsight/models/LanguageModel.py", line 149, in _load
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(repo_id, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/configuration_auto.py", line 928, in from_pretrained
    config_dict, unused_kwargs = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 631, in get_config_dict
    config_dict, kwargs = cls._get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 686, in _get_config_dict
    resolved_config_file = cached_file(
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 398, in cached_file
    resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 114, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/crayhippo/tag_peek/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1132, in hf_hub_download
    warnings.warn(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/warnings.py", line 109, in _showwarnmsg
    sw(msg.message, msg.category, msg.filename, msg.lineno,
  File "/Users/crayhippo/feature-circuits/circuit_gpt2.py", line 36, in warn_with_traceback
    warnings.warn(message, category, stacklevel=2)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/warnings.py", line 109, in _showwarnmsg
    sw(msg.message, msg.category, msg.filename, msg.lineno,
  File "/Users/crayhippo/feature-circuits/circuit_gpt2.py", line 35, in warn_with_traceback
    traceback.print_stack()

For more information, here is the full pip list
Package                    Version
-------------------------- --------------
accelerate                 0.30.1
aiohttp                    3.9.5
aiosignal                  1.3.1
annotated-types            0.6.0
anyio                      4.3.0
appnope                    0.1.4
argon2-cffi                23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings       21.2.0
Arpeggio                   2.0.2
arrow                      1.3.0
asttokens                  2.4.1
async-lru                  2.0.4
async-timeout              4.0.3
attrs                      23.2.0
automated-interpretability 0.0.3
babe                       0.0.7
Babel                      2.15.0
beartype                   0.14.1
beautifulsoup4             4.12.3
better-abc                 0.0.3
bidict                     0.23.1
bleach                     6.1.0
blobfile                   2.1.1
boostedblob                0.15.3
certifi                    2024.2.2
cffi                       1.16.0
charset-normalizer         3.3.2
circuitsvis                1.43.2
click                      8.1.7
colorama                   0.4.6
comm                       0.2.2
config2py                  0.1.33
contourpy                  1.2.1
cycler                     0.12.1
dataclasses-json           0.6.6
datasets                   2.19.1
debugpy                    1.8.1
decorator                  5.1.1
defusedxml                 0.7.1
diffusers                  0.27.2
dill                       0.3.8
docker-pycreds             0.4.0
dol                        0.2.45
eindex-callum              0.1.1
einops                     0.7.0
exceptiongroup             1.2.1
executing                  2.0.1
fancy-einsum               0.0.3
fastjsonschema             2.19.1
filelock                   3.14.0
fonttools                  4.51.0
fqdn                       1.5.1
frozenlist                 1.4.1
fsspec                     2024.3.1
gdb-tools                  1.5
ghp-import                 2.1.0
gitdb                      4.0.11
GitPython                  3.1.43
gprof2dot                  2022.7.29
graphviz                   0.20.3
graze                      0.1.15
griffe                     0.45.0
h11                        0.14.0
httpcore                   1.0.5
httpx                      0.27.0
huggingface-hub            0.23.0
i2                         0.1.17
idna                       3.7
importlib_metadata         7.1.0
importlib_resources        6.4.0
iniconfig                  2.0.0
ipykernel                  6.29.4
ipython                    8.24.0
ipywidgets                 8.1.2
isoduration                20.11.0
jaxtyping                  0.2.28
jedi                       0.19.1
Jinja2                     3.1.4
joblib                     1.4.2
json5                      0.9.25
jsonpointer                2.4
jsonschema                 4.22.0
jsonschema-specifications  2023.12.1
jupyter                    1.0.0
jupyter_client             8.6.1
jupyter-console            6.6.3
jupyter_core               5.7.2
jupyter-events             0.10.0
jupyter-lsp                2.2.5
jupyter_server             2.14.0
jupyter_server_terminals   0.5.3
jupyterlab                 4.1.8
jupyterlab_pygments        0.3.0
jupyterlab_server          2.27.1
jupyterlab_widgets         3.0.10
kiwisolver                 1.4.5
llvmlite                   0.42.0
lxml                       4.9.4
Markdown                   3.6
markdown-it-py             3.0.0
MarkupSafe                 2.1.5
marshmallow                3.21.2
matplotlib                 3.8.4
matplotlib-inline          0.1.7
mdurl                      0.1.2
mergedeep                  1.3.4
mistune                    3.0.2
mkdocs                     1.6.0
mkdocs-autorefs            1.0.1
mkdocs-get-deps            0.2.0
mkdocs-material            9.5.22
mkdocs-material-extensions 1.3.1
mkdocs-section-index       0.3.9
mkdocstrings               0.24.3
mkdocstrings-python        1.10.0
mpmath                     1.3.0
multidict                  6.0.5
multiprocess               0.70.16
mypy-extensions            1.0.0
nbclient                   0.10.0
nbconvert                  7.16.4
nbformat                   5.10.4
nest-asyncio               1.6.0
networkx                   3.3
nltk                       3.8.1
nnsight                    0.2.15
notebook                   7.1.3
notebook_shim              0.2.4
numba                      0.59.1
numpy                      1.26.4
orjson                     3.10.3
overrides                  7.7.0
packaging                  24.0
paginate                   0.5.6
pandas                     2.2.2
pandocfilters              1.5.1
parso                      0.8.4
pathspec                   0.12.1
patsy                      0.5.6
pexpect                    4.9.0
pillow                     10.3.0
pip                        24.0
platformdirs               4.2.1
plotly                     5.22.0
plotly-express             0.4.1
pluggy                     1.5.0
prometheus_client          0.20.0
prompt-toolkit             3.0.43
protobuf                   4.25.3
psutil                     5.9.8
ptyprocess                 0.7.0
pure-eval                  0.2.2
py2store                   0.1.20
pyarrow                    16.0.0
pyarrow-hotfix             0.6
pycparser                  2.22
pycryptodomex              3.20.0
pydantic                   2.7.1
pydantic_core              2.18.2
Pygments                   2.18.0
pymdown-extensions         10.8.1
pynndescent                0.5.12
pyparsing                  3.1.2
pytest                     8.2.0
pytest-profiling           1.7.0
python-dateutil            2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv              1.0.1
python-engineio            4.9.0
python-json-logger         2.0.7
python-socketio            5.11.2
pytz                       2024.1
PyYAML                     6.0.1
pyyaml_env_tag             0.1
pyzmq                      26.0.0
qtconsole                  5.5.2
QtPy                       2.4.1
referencing                0.35.1
regex                      2024.5.10
requests                   2.31.0
rfc3339-validator          0.1.4
rfc3986-validator          0.1.1
rich                       13.7.1
rpds-py                    0.18.1
sae-lens                   2.1.1
sae-vis                    0.2.18
safetensors                0.4.3
scikit-learn               1.4.2
scipy                      1.13.0
seaborn                    0.13.2
Send2Trash                 1.8.3
sentencepiece              0.2.0
sentry-sdk                 2.1.1
setproctitle               1.3.3
setuptools                 68.2.2
shellingham                1.5.4
simple-websocket           1.0.0
six                        1.16.0
smmap                      5.0.1
sniffio                    1.3.1
soupsieve                  2.5
stack-data                 0.6.3
statsmodels                0.14.2
sympy                      1.12
tenacity                   8.3.0
terminado                  0.18.1
threadpoolctl              3.5.0
tiktoken                   0.6.0
tinycss2                   1.3.0
tokenizers                 0.19.1
tomli                      2.0.1
torch                      2.3.0
torchtyping                0.1.4
torchvision                0.18.0
tornado                    6.4
tqdm                       4.66.1
traitlets                  5.14.3
transformer-lens           1.17.0
transformers               4.40.2
typeguard                  2.13.3
typer                      0.12.3
types-python-dateutil      2.9.0.20240316
typing_extensions          4.11.0
typing-inspect             0.9.0
tzdata                     2024.1
umap                       0.1.1
umap-learn                 0.5.6
uri-template               1.3.0
urllib3                    2.2.1
uvloop                     0.19.0
wandb                      0.17.0
watchdog                   4.0.0
wcwidth                    0.2.13
webcolors                  1.13
webencodings               0.5.1
websocket-client           1.8.0
widgetsnbextension         4.0.10
wsproto                    1.2.0
xxhash                     3.4.1
yarl                       1.9.4
zipp                       3.18.1
zstandard                  0.22.0

